# Working on the same branch in all Git repositores

Tags: git

I have several repositories and usually when there is branch A in one of the repositories, there is also a branch with the same name in the rest.

Is there a way to make sure that when i switch to branch A in one of the repositories, the branch will be switched in the other as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to make sure that when I switch to branch `A` in one of the repositories, the branch will be switched in the other as well?

Not with basic Git commands alone.

A less basic Git command *could* achieve something similar with [`git subtree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt): see "[Alternatives To Git Submodule: Git Subtree](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/) ", and "[Working with subtree merge](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-subtree-merge)": you merge several repos in one, while preserving the possibility to export back the history of those sub-repos back to their original repos.
While you are in that "merged repo", making a branch would apply to *all* merged repos.

But the one tool which does *precisely* what you want is called **[gitslave](http://gitslave.sourceforge.net/)**

> Gitslave creates a group of related repositories—a superproject repository and a number of slave repositories—all of which are concurrently developed on and on which all git operations should normally operate;
>   **so when you branch, each repository in the project is branched in turn. Similarly when you commit, push, pull, merge, tag, checkout, status, log, etc; each git command will run on the superproject and all slave repositories in turn**.
>   This sort of activity may be very familiar to CVS and (to a lesser extent) Subversion users. Gitslave's design is for simplicity for normal git operations.